# Does assert_approx_eq exists for ndarray?

Tags: multidimensional-array, rust

I'm referring to the [ndarray](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.13.1/ndarray/) crate as well as the [assert_approx_eq](https://crates.io/crates/assert_approx_eq).

My question: Does something like `assert_approx_eq` exist for `ndarray::Array2` etc.?

Currently I'm doing:

```
for it in mat_a.iter().zip(expect_mat_a.iter()) {
  let (af, bf) = it;
  assert_approx_eq!(af, bf);
}
```

This is works, but is sub-optimal.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, ndarray has the optional feature `approx` and with it enabled, it supports the [`approx`](https://docs.rs/approx/0.4.0/approx/) crate traits and macros.

```rust
use approx::assert_abs_diff_eq;

assert_abs_diff_eq!(af, bf);
```

Answer (score 0):

> My question: Does something like `assert_approx_eq` exist for `ndarray::Array2` etc.?

Wouldn't think so, that's quite specific and `ndarray` doesn't seem to provide anything similar.

> ```
> for it in mat_a.iter().zip(expect_mat_a.iter()) {
>      let (af, bf) = it;
>      assert_approx_eq!(af, bf);
> }
> ```

You should be able to simplify that a small bit by deconstructing the tuple straight into the iteration:

```rust
for (af, bf) in mat_a.iter().zip(expect_mat_a.iter()) {
  assert_approx_eq!(af, bf);
}
```

> This is works, but is sub-optimal.

Syntactically? You can hide the implementation behind a macro of your own. That is basically what `assert_approx_eq` does, it's nothing magical, it just provides conveniences / convenient defaults, mostly in that it generates an expressive error message on failure, if you look at the code `assert_approx_eq!($a, $b)` just desugars to:

```rust
        let eps = 1.0e-6;
        let (a, b) = (&$a, &$b);
        assert!(
            (*a - *b).abs() < eps,
            "assertion failed: `(left !== right)` \
             (left: `{:?}`, right: `{:?}`, expect diff: `{:?}`, real diff: `{:?}`)",
            *a,
            *b,
            eps,
            (*a - *b).abs()
        );
```

Comment: There is an approx feature in the crate. See creanion's answer.